# Como ampliar el alto de todos los elementos de una fila de bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy trabajando con bootstrap 4.6 y tengo una fila con dos columnas, quisiera que ambos elementos tenga el mismo alto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
      <div class="card">
         <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-12">
                  <p class="text-justify">Se realizara una revisión de todos los datos..
                  </p>
               </div>
               <div class="col-12 align-self-stretch my-2">
                  <a class="btn btn-info d-lg-inline-flex float-right my-1"
                     href="{{ route('ficha_estudiantes.index') }}">
                  Revisión
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="card">
         <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
               <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group form-check">
                     <input id="anio_pasado_estudio" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"
                     onclick="javascript: return false;" @if ($inscripcion->anio_pasado_estudio == 1)
                     {{ 'checked' }}
                     @endif/>
                     <label class="form-check-label" for="anio_pasado_estudio">¿El año pasado
                     estudió?</label>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group form-check">
                     <input id="ultimo_curso_aprobo" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"
                     name="ultimo_curso_aprobo"
                     onclick="javascript: return false;" @if ($inscripcion->ultimo_curso_aprobo == 1)
                     {{ 'checked' }}
                     @endif/>
                     <label class="form-check-label" for="ultimo_curso_aprobo">¿El último curso
                     estudiado lo aprobó?</label>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group form-check">
                     <input id="viene_colegio_publico" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"
                     name="viene_colegio_publico"
                     onclick="javascript: return false;" @if ($inscripcion->viene_colegio_publico == 1)
                     {{ 'checked' }}
                     @endif/>
                     <label class="form-check-label" for="viene_colegio_publico">¿Viene de colegio
                     público?</label>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <form method="post" action="{{ route('inscripciones.update', $inscripcion->id) }}">
                     @csrf
                     @method("PATCH")
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="estado_ins">Estado de la inscripción</label><span
                           class="text-danger">*</span>
                        {!! Form::select('inscripcion_estados_id', $estados, $inscripcion->inscripcion_estados_id, ['id' => 'inscripciones_estados_id', 'class' => 'form-control select2']) !!}
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                     </div>
                  </form>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3 align-self-center ml-2">
                  <button id="enviar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"
                     tabindex="1">
                  Enviar
                  </button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Como respuesta parcial, si solo quieres que se alineen en vertical, pon la clase .h-100 en la division que tenga la clase .card esta hara que tome la altura 100% de su parent, pero esto no hara que el contenido se centre o acomode dentro de el

Comment: @masterguru si bro, disculpa, apenas me di cuenta, necesito el alto. Lo pude medio arreglar con el .h-100 pero los elementos de la tarjeta en resoluciones sm se descuadran y creo que es por eso.

Comment: ¿Que quieres decir con que se te descuadran?  Las resoluciones sm las tienes puestas en 12 columnas mediante `col-sm-12`, por lo tanto las columnas se apilan

Comment: Lo que pasa es que los botones en la resolución sm se sale del .card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como afirma en el comentario @Stial Manstike solo hace falta agregar h-100. por defecto bootstrap pone las columnas con el mismo alto, pero el contenido que pones dentro de la columna si no se ajusta al 100% no estará alineado.

Lo he comprobado con:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body class>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col card">
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col card"><ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>4</li>
        </ul></div>
        <div class="col card"><ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
        </ul></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

En tu caso el hijo de la primera columna tiene esta altura (borde inferior en rojo):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agregando `h-100` al hijo directo de las columnas:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
           <div class="card h-100">
              <div class="card-body">
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                       <p class="text-justify">Se realizara una revisión de todos los datos..
                       </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 align-self-stretch my-2">
                       <a class="btn btn-info d-lg-inline-flex float-right my-1"
                          href="{{ route('ficha_estudiantes.index') }}">
                       Revisión
                       </a>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
           <div class="card h-100">
              <div class="card-body">
                 <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                       <div class="form-group form-check">
                          <input id="anio_pasado_estudio" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"
                          onclick="javascript: return false;" @if ($inscripcion->anio_pasado_estudio == 1)
                          {{ 'checked' }}
                          @endif/>
                          <label class="form-check-label" for="anio_pasado_estudio">¿El año pasado
                          estudió?</label>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                       <div class="form-group form-check">
                          <input id="ultimo_curso_aprobo" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"
                          name="ultimo_curso_aprobo"
                          onclick="javascript: return false;" @if ($inscripcion->ultimo_curso_aprobo == 1)
                          {{ 'checked' }}
                          @endif/>
                          <label class="form-check-label" for="ultimo_curso_aprobo">¿El último curso
                          estudiado lo aprobó?</label>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                       <div class="form-group form-check">
                          <input id="viene_colegio_publico" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"
                          name="viene_colegio_publico"
                          onclick="javascript: return false;" @if ($inscripcion->viene_colegio_publico == 1)
                          {{ 'checked' }}
                          @endif/>
                          <label class="form-check-label" for="viene_colegio_publico">¿Viene de colegio
                          público?</label>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                       <form method="post" action="{{ route('inscripciones.update', $inscripcion->id) }}">
                          @csrf
                          @method("PATCH")
                          <div class="form-group">
                             <label for="estado_ins">Estado de la inscripción</label><span
                                class="text-danger">*</span>
                             {!! Form::select('inscripcion_estados_id', $estados, $inscripcion->inscripcion_estados_id, ['id' => 'inscripciones_estados_id', 'class' => 'form-control select2']) !!}
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                          </div>
                       </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 align-self-center ml-2">
                       <button id="enviar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"
                          tabindex="1">
                       Enviar
                       </button>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*ver en pantalla completa

Comment: Aplique la respuesta y si obtengo el efecto esperado pero me genera un problema, los botones parecen que no quedan responsivas y sin .h-100 si funcionan bien

Comment: como dice [Responsive Buttons with Bootstrap - travishorn](https://travishorn.com/responsive-buttons-with-bootstrap-7c2a7c144308) utiliza la clase `btn-block` para ajustar el ancho al mismo del padre. (el problema es similar al de coincidir alturas), en ambos el problema es que está poniendo correctamente las medidas al nodo padre, pero al nodo hijo le permites ser diferente.

Comment: Yo estoy usando btn-block y funciona bien sin el .h-100, me puedes explicar, soy nuevo, gracias.